# Dumping a ROM image completely

Tags: rom-flashing, backup, recovery-mode, twrp, rom

As you know when we compile SDK or download a stock ROM, it contains some partitions(system,recovery,boot,...). We can unpack this image to partitions with some tools. (or with a simple C code)

But my question: Suppose we have a device with a burned image. Is there any way to gain the burned '.img' from its MMC?

I know Team Win(TWRP) can extract system, boot and recovery but bootloader is missing. How to access the original image file? (So I can burn this image on a similar device if it is bricked. (suppose the image is not on the Internet!)

Thanks

Comment: You can use `dd` to make image of any partition.

Comment: Is it requires root? @Firelord

Comment: I know it already but do you have tested it? It seems something may be wrong. @Firelord